# Find loop not working correctly

Tags: loops, find

I am trying to design a vba macro script for Mac Office 2011 that uses find in column A to find a filename previously selected by the user.

The user selects a .csv file, then macro looks through column A to find filename without .csv extension. Once found, it offsets by one column (to column B) and imports the csv information.

What I currently have is not doing the find and then select? I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

The csv will import, but just next to the cell I had active before running macro. This is why I think the Find is not working.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
Sub CSVauto()
'
' CSVauto Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+x
'
'   Declaring and setting variables for choosing CSV to import
    Dim csvFileName As Variant


''Prompt window to choose csv file
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="")
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub
'Setting a variable to find Experimental form name in Data Summary
Dim whatToFind As String 'Declaring that variable
    If Right(csvFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then
        whatToFind = Replace(csvFileName, ".csv", "")
    Else
        MsgBox "Selected File Not .csv)"
    End If
'Looping through A column to find csvFileName without .csv extension
Set cell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=whatToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        cell.Select
    End If

'Speeding macro up by making it work in background
 Sheets("DataSummary").DisplayPageBreaks = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

MyRange.Select

 'xlOverwriteCells

 On Error Resume Next

'Formatting for CSV and input
With MyRange.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFileName, Destination:=MyRange)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False
    End With

 'Formatting DataSummary sheet to fit "requirements" :)
    Cells.Replace What:=">=", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="C121", Replacement:="C2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="P1211", Replacement:="P21", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
    End With

    Range("A4").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Insert your code here.
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop

    'undoing everything working in background
    Sheets("DataSummary").DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at where you "Set cell =...." you are having it look for whatToFind.

In your if/else statement above that, you never set whatToFind in the "else" statement. You need to set whatToFind as something in the else statement, if I am reading your request correctly.

It looks to me what you are asking for is to find a file that is NOT a .csv then to perform the function of searching/offset.

Please correct me if I am wrong or please clarify.

EDIT

This code should work for you. I tried it with your code with this inserted just below the if/else statement

`Dim filename As Variant
filename = Mid(whatToFind, InStrRev(whatToFind, "/") + 1)
MsgBox filename`

Comment: What I am doing is manually typing the file name (without .csv) in column A. First I have the GetOpenFileName bring up a window to choose a csv. Then I want it to search column A for that filename (without .csv). Once found, offset by one column and import the information in the .csv file. Even taking out the If/else statement the find still is not working correctly

Comment: Found the issue, but not sure how to fix it. When it loops through column A it is looking for the full filename path instead of testname.csv. It looks for Macintosh HD:Users:joshuacarter:Desktop:path:to:filname. Any idea of how to get it to just look for the filename only and not the full path?

Comment: @JJcarter check out the edit above. that worked for me on your code and should work for you